# Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I recently set up direct image uploads to my Amazon S3 bucket following the tutorial created my Heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#define-the-file-attribute-in-the-model).

When I upload the file, it is successfully sent to my S3 bucket, but when I try to save the image I get the following error

```
    Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError at /photos
No handler found for "//mys3bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/3452345aef45845blabla/the file name.fileExtension"
```

Here is the form in my view:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @photo, html: { multipart: true, class: 'directUpload', data: { 'form-data' => (@s3_direct_post.fields), 'url' => @s3_direct_post.url, 'host' => URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host } } do |f| %>

    <p>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>

    <%= f.submit 'Upload', class: 'btn btn-success' %>

  <% end %>
```

Here is my create method in my controller:

```
  def create
    if can? :create, Photo
      @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
      if @photo.save
        redirect_to photos_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

      private

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:image, :title)
  end

  def set_s3_direct_post
    @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
  end
```

Here is my model:

```
    class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
    belongs_to :article

    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :image,
        attachment_content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ },
        attachment_size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }

end
```

Here is my entire [repository](https://github.com/bfbachmann/Blog)

I understand that for some reason Paperclip does not know how to handle the URL but I have no idea how to fix this. I tried adding a new column to my Photos table in my database and just saving the URL to that column. That worked perfectly of course because Paperclip was not involved. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would appear that I have found the answer. I don't think it's the best way of doing it because I am essentially bypassing Paperclip but at this point whatever.

I changed my model and database to just accept a url string instead of an attachment with the following code:

**/models/photo.rb**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :image_url, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

**First Migration**

```
class RemoveAttatchedImageFromPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :photos, :attached_image_file_name
    remove_column :photos, :attached_image_content_type
    remove_column :photos, :attached_image_file_size
    remove_column :photos, :attached_image_updated_at
  end
end
```

**Second Migration**

```
 class AddImageUrlToPhoto2 < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :photos, :image_url, :string
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add **s3_host_name** to your configuration?

Like:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
 storage: :s3,
 s3_host_name: "s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com", #example
 s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
 s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have what you posted in development.rb and I still get the same error.